# Understanding makefile

Tags: makefile

I have an error here, but it should work actually:

> make: Fatal error in reader: /x/y/z/compile.mak, line 22: Extra :', ::', or :=' on dependency line`

```
${COPY_FILES:src/%=${STAGING_DIR}/%} : ${STAGING_DIR}/% : src/%
 mkdir -p ${@D}
 rm -f ${@}
 cp ${<} ${@}
 chmod ${FILE_PERMISSIONS} ${@}
```

How can this be fixed?

```
COPY_FILES - is a list of files,
STAGING_DIR - path,
FILE_PERMISSIONS - 444
```

Comment: I have an error here, but it should work actually:
``make: Fatal error in reader: /x/y/z/compile.mak, line 22: Extra `:', `::', or `:=' on dependency line``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message so helpfully and succinctly says, you have an extra `:` on the dependency line. I'm guessing this line:

```
${COPY_FILES:src/%=${STAGING_DIR}/%} : ${STAGING_DIR}/% : src/%
```

should probably be:

```
${COPY_FILES:src/%=${STAGING_DIR}/%} : ${STAGING_DIR}/% src/%
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul R!

But I would like also to know, how does this section works.
I know the basis of make system, but that is too complicated for me.
to understand this I could read a lot of manuals, but don't have time for it, unfortunately..

Comment: @KeKc: you should probably read the GNU make manual if you want to learn about this stuff: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html - in the above example though it just seems to be copying all source files from one directory to a temporary staging directory where the permissions are then changed.

Comment: Ok, clearmake doesn't show this error. so I should look to it's manual.
Thank you, @Paul R!